# Control distance of the boundary

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold with boundary $\partial M$. Let $(g_t)_{0\leq t\leq T}$ be a family of Riemannian metrics with $g_0=g$. Suppose that $\partial M$ has at least two connected components. Suppose that there exists $C>0$ such that $|Rm(g_t)|_{g_t}\leq C$ and $|\mathcal{A}(g_t)|_{g^T_t}\leq C$ for all $0\leq t\leq T$. Here $\mathcal{A}(g_t)$ is the second fundamental form of $\partial M$ and $g^T_t$ the restriction of $g_t$ to $\partial M$. Is there $c>0$ such that the distance of two components of $(\partial M,g^T_t)$ is bounded below by $c$ (uniformly in $t$)?

Comment: It should be a classical theorem from comparison geometry. A reference to proof is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, consider a part of Lobachevsky plane bounded by two asymptotically parallel lines.

Comment: P.S. the question makes better sense if $M$ is compact and the $t\in [0,T)$, but the answer is "no" anyway.

Comment: Yes. I consider $M$ to be compact. Let me explain why I ask the question above. I need to know whether or not the boundary injectivity radius of $(M,g_t)$ is bounded from below by a uniform constant. Maybe if $(g_t)$ is uniformly equivalent, it will work? Recall that the boundary injectivity radius is the maximal $r>0$ such that a $r$-tubolar neiborhood of $\partial M$ is diffeomorphic to $\partial M\times[0,r)$ via the normal exponential map of $\partial M$.

Comment: @Nguyen, Okey $M$ is compact; if time interval $\mathbb{I}$ is compact as well then you get a bound from compactness of $M\times\mathbb{I}$. If $\mathbb{I}$  is not compact then I can give an example (it has bounded diamter as well); are you interested? (So in a sense there is no uniform bound.)

Comment: Yes. Give an example please.

Comment: @Nguyen the simplest one is an annulus for radiuses $t$ and $T$. If you want to keep area bounded away from zero, then you can take the region between two circles of fixed radiuses so that the distance between the circles converes to zero.